# PHP - SELECT * FROM ... but view last element in database first

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

Hey, first of all thanks for helping me out with this (probably stupid) question :)
I did my research but can't find any solutions on google.

Is it possible to start viewing the last element in my database?

for example:

DATABASE (comments):

```
name | comment

jan  | Test
bert | Test2
sam  | Test3
```

PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comments";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $rows['name'];
echo $rows['comment'];

}
```

THE RESULT:

```
jan Test
bert Test2
sam Test3
```

MY PURPOSE:

```
sam Test3
bert Test2
jan Test
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your mysql query to sort the result set how you want. In your case it is probably something like

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add either an id to your table, or at least a timestamp that contains the time and date of insertion of your data row.

Then :

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```